# Solving area of quadrilateral from given values

Tags: geometry

I have a quadrilateral ABCD. The intersection of its diagonals is labelled E.

I've been given the value of the angles $\angle$ABC and $\angle$ACD (both 90°), the lengths of AC (20) and CD(30), as well as the length of AE(5). I've managed to entirely solve one half of the quadrilateral, but am now stuck when it comes to figuring out the other half.

GeoGebra render of what is known already:

[image]

As shown in the image, I now know the lengths of EC(15), AD($10\sqrt{13}$), and ED($15\sqrt{5}$), as well as the values of the angles $\angle$ADC($90-\arctan{1.5}$), $\angle$CAD($\arctan{1.5}$), and $\angle$CED($\arctan{2}$).

I'm unable to find the length of AB, BC or BE, nor either of the angles $\angle$BAC or $\angle$BCA. I would like help in finding a method to solve for any of these values.

If it helps, the original question asks for the area of this quadrilateral. While I've already determined what the area must be, I have yet to be able to prove it.

Comment: Alt. hint: let $P$ be the midpoint of $AC$, then calculate $BE$ from $\triangle PEB$ where you know two sides $PB = AC/2,PE=AC/2-AE$ and angle $\angle PEB$, then calculate the height from $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Method 1(Using Coordinates):

Take $A ≡ (0,0)$ , $C ≡ (20,0)$, $D ≡ (20,-30)$. Construct a circle whose centre is on the midpoint of $AC$. Let $O ≡ (10,0)$. Equation of circle is $(x-10)^2 + (y-0)^2 = 10^2$. Let E be a point on AC such that $AE = 5$. Therefore $E ≡ (5,0)$. Calculate equation of line DE which comes to be $\frac{y-(-30)}{x-20} = \frac{0-(-30)}{5-20}$. Solve the equation of circle and line and then find the coordinates of B. After that find the area.

Method 2(Plain Geometry):

Calculate angle AED using cosine rule. Call $AB$ as $a$ and $BE$ as d. Apply apollonius Theorem to $∆BAO$ and find a relation between $a$ and $d$ . Call that $(I)$. Apply cosine rule to $∆BAE$ to find another relation between $a$ and $d$. Call that $(II)$. Solve $(I)$ and $(II)$ to get the value of $a$. Calculate the area from that.

[image]

Comment: While I didn't quite use the exact method described here, the insight about the midpoint of AC and the circle did end up leading to the solution. Thank you for answering so thoroughly!

Comment: The key to solve this question is to find the 'cause' of right angle. Since, angle in a semicircle is $90°$, therefore we have to imagine a circle.